# mysql create trigger inside stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers, mysql-workbench

How can I create a trigger by executing a stored procedure in mysql. If it is not possible please explain the reasons.
Is there any way to create triggers dinamicaly without creating each every time?

Comment: Have you tried creating it inside an `Events`? Like by executing the `Trigger` inside of an `Event` instead of a `Stored Procedure`, because in `Events` you could schedule when you want it to be executed.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain the problem you're trying to solve with this. Almost certainly there's another, and possibly better, way

Comment: I have 50 of table in my database. I need to create a stored procedure to create an audit table for each table by calling the stored procedure. And also need to create triggers when creating an audit table.. I try to add trigger creation part inside the sp but it is given a error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If it is not possible please explain the reasons.

---

[MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual / Stored Objects / Restrictions on Stored Programs # SQL Statements Not Permitted in Stored Routines](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html#stored-routine-sql-restrictions)

> Generally, **statements not permitted in SQL prepared statements are also not permitted in stored programs**. For a list of statements supported as prepared statements, see Section 13.5, “Prepared Statements”. Exceptions are SIGNAL, RESIGNAL, and GET DIAGNOSTICS, which are not permissible as prepared statements but are permitted in stored programs.

[MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual / SQL Statements / Prepared Statements # SQL Syntax Permitted in Prepared Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html#prepared-statements-permitted)

The complete list of the statements allowed is provided. There is no CREATE TRIGGER statement in this list.

Hence, trigger cannot be created in stored procedure.

---

But you can create a trigger and influence its execution. For example, you can create some service table in the database, and check the values stored in it in the trigger code - use them as parameters or execute/skip various blocks of code.

This corresponds to the principle "client code should not perform DDL operations" also.